# aligning input tags using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.label{
padding: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
} 


input{
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<label class="label">user </label><input type="text" name="usr"/><br>
<label class="label">pass </label><input type="text" name="pass"/><br>
<label class="label">user </label><input type="text" name="rpass"/><br>
```

I'm new to css, and I want to align my textfields but when I run it I see that the text fields are not in a line. Maybe because of the `label` tag. Should I write css to label tag ? Can you help with this css properties?

Comment: remove br http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/5bue5yv7/ or http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/s2m7a1gb/  and why tag(label) javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its unclear what you mean by they are not aligned. I tried it in a fiddle and they look horizontally aligned to me. My guess is that your labels are of different lengths and are therefore pushing the inputs to different distances to the right. To fix this add styling to your labels to set them to be the same width regardless of the content. To do this try

```
.label{
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    /* Don't necessarily use 40px, try and figure out what works best for your case */
 }
```

Comment: yeah i had labels with different lengths applying css to labels affected on
input tags too

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `<br>` tag, it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/TheBlueLabCo/y5xbgjt9/ or the [Full Screen result](https://jsfiddle.net/TheBlueLabCo/y5xbgjt9/embedded/result/).